# laravel 5 Access denied for user 'root'@' localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel5. I tried to create migration table but I get this error

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvEey.png)

This is the database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'larashop'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'melody'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and this is .env

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=larashop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=melody
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. Im having same issue:/

Comment: I am using phpMyadmin when i change password to root and change  DB_PASSWORD="root" in env .It works

Answer (score -1):

Your screenshot shows "localhost" and your code shows "127.0.0.1".  MySQL treats "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" differently.

Make sure you have granted appropriate permissions for 'root'@'localhost' in your database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 90;